# R: how to map a set of integers to another set of integers

Tags: r, integer

I have a data set where each individual has a unique person ID. I'm interested in turning these ID numbers to another set of more manageable type `integer` IDs.

```
ID <- c(59970013552, 51730213552, 1233923, 2949394, 9999999999)
```

Essentially, I'd like to map these IDs a `new_ID`, where

```
> new_ID
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

The reason I'm doing this is that my analysis requires `as.integer(ID)`, and R will coerce large integers into `NA`. I have tried using `as.integer64` from the `bit64` package, but the class `integer64` is not compatible with my analysis.

I've also thought to just do `ID - min(ID) + 1` to get around having huge ID numbers. But this also doesn't work, because some of my larger IDs are so large that even if I subtract the `min(ID)` value, `as.integer(ID)` will still coerce them to `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a duplicate but I couldn't find a relevant answer hence posting an answer.

We can use `match`

```
match(ID, unique(ID))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

OR convert the `ID` into `factor`s along with `levels`

```
as.integer(factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you show how I can use this to map `ID2 <- c(51730213552, 59970013552, 9999999999, 2949394, 1233923)` (just `ID` but order is changed) to the desired `2 1 5 4 3`?

Comment: Ah..I think I got it. It's just `match(ID2, unique(ID))`

Comment: @Adrian yep. That should do it.